# Can Go code generate dll in windows or can C ++/C# call golang code?

Tags: go

Can Go functions be called by `C++` or `C#` code on windows? Does Go support generating dll in Windows?

Comment: I know gccgo is sometimes more compatible this way, but I don't think even it can compile to a DLL yet...

Comment: Some work in that direction has been undertaken, see [issue 11058](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11058). August 2016: not done yet.

Answer (score 9):

No, Go code is statically linked. The reason for this is Go's runtime, which is embeded in every executable, among other things.

---

Edit:

It is apparently possible with a lot of indirection, but far from usable in practice.
See [Call go functions from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125683/call-go-functions-from-c) and the linked blog posts for more information.