# How to execute Go function in C#

Tags: c#, go

Is there any way to execute a Go function from C#? For Python I would use Ironpython for example.

I know that I could spawn a process to execute a Go script, but I don't really want to fallback to such a solution, if possible.

A Google search didn't reveal anything, so is there any way to do that using an API? Or do I have to fallback on processes?

Comment: When you're invoking a process, you can read it's output in your C# code. There are probably numerous examples on SO. I'm not aware of any interop between Go and C#/the CLR though it wouldn't surprise me if there's one out there.

Comment: @evan Well, didn't know that. Thanks. But I'll still prefer an API though :)

Comment: Just based of a quick Google search I don't think you're going to be finding any API for Go - C# interop.

Comment: Can you use the Tardis Go Transpiler? https://tardisgo.github.io/  (Disclaimer: I have no Go experience)

Comment: @user2023861 yeah, I guess I could. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: my answer is now not true, since Go has been updated since I posted.  [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19919835/3960399) will help you solve your problem.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

I don't think you're going to have much luck finding what you're looking for.  [Go is statically linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720425/can-go-code-generate-dll-in-windows-or-can-c-c-call-golang-code) and [C# doesn't support that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729562/how-to-compile-c-sharp-application-with-c-static-library).

From C#, [calling a pre-compiled executable and reading the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results) is the easiest thing I can think of.

Comment: this question is not true anymore. go now can be dynamically build and can be called from languages like c, c++,c# etc..

Comment: @cahitbeyaz could you add some links how to run golang code with taking into account CLR security constrains?

Comment: @cahitbeyaz still can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 5):

I think Frank's answer is not right! Golang supports many build mode, and one is c-shared mode, it means you can use it like a c module.
e.g:
https://www.trs.ai/c%E8%B0%83%E7%94%A8golang%E4%BB%A3%E7%A0%81/

Comment: link is deprecated, this thread might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431296/building-and-linking-dynamically-from-a-go-binary

Answer (score -1):

you can use [grpc](https://grpc.io/) implement calls
grpc works across languages and platforms