# Is it possible to make go packages a .so or .a file?

Tags: go, cgo

Recently I have spent some time on cgo and how to write C codes in go. It seems very easy to load a .so file by using #cgo directives. However, are there any ways that we can do this in a opposite way? That is, can we build a go package to a .so or .a file so that it can be used by c/c++ projects directly?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125683/call-go-functions-from-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is Go code can't be dynamically loaded into C code **yet**.

There is some activity on making this possible, but it isn't ready now.

See [the discussion at on the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/golang-nuts/zmjXkGrEx6Q).