# Is there a way to create bindings for golang library for node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dll, go, network-programming

The situation is very simple: I have a node.js application and want it to be able to call functions from my networking library written in golang. As far as I understand there are numerous wrappers around c/c++ code in node, can I create a one around my golang library?

There is a tool gopy http://gopy.qur.me/extensions/install.html which solves this problem for python, but I was unable to found something similar for node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible right now to build shared library in golang. There's an issue talking about this in [golang repos](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/256) and a document describing the [go execution mode](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nr-TQHw_er6GOQRsF6T43GGhFDelrAP0NqSS_00RgZQ/edit#heading=h.fwmrrio0df0i).

A discussion about this [Call Go functions from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125683/call-go-functions-from-c)