# Using Go on existing C project

Tags: c, go, gccgo

I have a program entirely written in C that uses multiple object `(.o)` files in it. These files are all packed inside an archive file `(.a)` which, in turn, is used at compile-time of the program's main `(.c)` file.

I want to write a new file for this project in Go. My idea is to write this `.go` file and then create an object `(.o)` file from it. Afterwards, I want to put this object file inside the already mentioned archive `(.a)` file.

This basically means that **I want to call Go functions from a C program**. I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125683/call-go-functions-from-c), and while it showed me that what I want is possible via GCCGO, it's not 100% clear as to how to do it.

Even with the most basic of tests, I get errors during the linking phase. More specifically, here's one of such basic example:

---

**printString.go**

```
package main

import
(
    "fmt"
)

func PrintString(buff string) int {
    fmt.Printf(buff)
    return 1
}
```

**c_caller.c**

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>

extern int PrintString(char*) __asm__ ("print.main.PrintString");

int main() {
    char *string_to_pass= NULL;
    asprintf(&string_to_pass, "This is a test.");

    int result= PrintString(string_to_pass);
    if(result) {printf("Everything went as expected!\n");}
    else       {printf("Uh oh, something went wrong!\n");}

    return result;
}
```

**Compiling**

In order to compile the Go file, I used this command:

```
gccgo -c printString.go -o printString.o -fgo-prefix=print -Wall -Werror -march=native
```

In order to compile the entire thing, I used this command:

```
gccgo -o main c_caller.c printString.o -Wall -Werror -march=native
```

The return message I'm getting is:

```
/usr/lib64/libgo.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `main.main'
/usr/lib64/libgo.so.4.0.0: undefined reference to `__go_init_main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which means that GCCGO's expecting a main function in the Go file instead of the C one.

Using the `--static-libgo`, `-static` and `-Wl,-R,/path/to/libgo.so's_folder` options on the second command yield a different result:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgo
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which makes no sense, since I have the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable properly pointing to libgo.so's folder.

---

I realize that I'm probably doing something wrong here, but I just can't see what that is. There's next to no examples of GCCGO and its interaction with C out there, and the only reference I could find was [this page](https://golang.org/doc/install/gccgo), which I personally feel like it's not enough.

I ask kindly for some advice on this matter and thank you for your time. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may not be what you want, but in **Go 1.5,** that's coming this August, you'll be able to build C-compatible libraries with the go tool. So with this in your `_main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *string_to_pass = NULL;
    if (asprintf(&string_to_pass, "This is a test.") < 0) {
        printf("asprintf fail");
        return -1;
    }

    PrintString(string_to_pass);
    return 0;
}
```

and this in your `main.go`

```
package main

import "C"
import "fmt"

//export PrintString
func PrintString(cs *C.char) {
    s := C.GoString(cs)
    fmt.Println(s)
}

func main() {}
```

You can do, for static library:

```
go build -buildmode c-archive -o mygopkg.a
gcc -o main _main.c mygopkg.a -lpthread
```

For shared library:

```
go build -buildmode c-shared -o mygopkg.so
LD_RUN_PATH=$(pwd) gcc -o main _main.c mygopkg.so -lpthread
```

(`LD_RUN_PATH` is here to make the linker look for the shared library in the same directory you're building.)

See the [Go execution modes design document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nr-TQHw_er6GOQRsF6T43GGhFDelrAP0NqSS_00RgZQ/edit) for more info.

Comment: A shame won't get to use it now, but it's nice to know the option will be there in the near future. Thank you for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

There currently isn't a supported way to do what you want. Go always needs the support of its runtime, and the entry point for that is always `main`. AFAIK, gccgo also makes these same assumptions, and doesn't provide a way to easily link into from other programs.

If you want to do this in a supported manner, you will have to wait until go1.5+ where work is being done to compile shared libraries from Go code.

If you really want to hack on this now, you can look into how the Android port works using the default gc toolchain with `-linkmode external`, which renames `main` in the object file and calls it externally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While the Android thing sounds like a decent way to get around this, waiting for version 1.5 sounds like "the way to go".