# Access Golang code from a C project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c, visual-studio, go

I have a C project in Visual Studio 2019 and I would like to use certain functions written in Go within it.

I have a test file called `ctest.go` which has the following contents:

```
package main

import (
    "C"
    "fmt"
)

//export printInt
func printInt(x int) {
    fmt.Printf("Hello from go: %d", x)
}

func main() {}
```

I'm generating a static library with this command:

```
go build -buildmode=c-archive ctest.go
```

I end up with two files, `ctest.a` and `ctest.h` which I include in my VS project. I include `ctest.h` in my code and immediately get these errors:

```
identifier "__SIZE_TYPE__" is undefined
expected a ';'
expected a ';'
```

The generated header file contains the following lines which caused it:

```
typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ GoUintptr;
typedef float _Complex GoComplex64;
typedef double _Complex GoComplex128;
```

I replaced `__SIZE_TYPE__` by `size_t` and just commented out the `_Complex` lines to stop the errors.

Now my VS project compiles while including the header file. But as soon as I try to use my go function like this:

```
printInt(5);
```

I get 2 warnings followed by 6 errors:

```
Warning LNK4078 multiple '.text' sections found with different attributes (60600060)    AWO F:\AWO\AWO\ctest.a(go.o)
Warning LNK4078 multiple '.text' sections found with different attributes (60600060)    AWO F:\AWO\AWO\ctest.a(go.o)
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp___iob referenced in function __cgo_preinit_init    AWO F:\AWO\AWO\ctest.a(000005.o)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___iob  AWO F:\AWO\AWO\ctest.a(000006.o)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp___iob  AWO F:\AWO\AWO\ctest.a(000007.o)
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _fprintf referenced in function _x_cgo_sys_thread_create AWO F:\AWO\AWO\ctest.a(000005.o)
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _fprintf AWO F:\AWO\AWO\ctest.a(000007.o)
Error   LNK1120 2 unresolved externals  AWO F:\AWO\Debug\AWO.exe    1
```

This is where I'm stuck. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or should be doing differently to properly use the library generated with go.

Comment: You're not linking the library.

Comment: I believe I am, I've added `ctest.a` to "Additional Dependencies" and its directory to "Additional Library Directories"

Comment: There is a lot here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125683/call-go-functions-from-c

Comment: I don't believe visual studio supports .a file format. Try compiling it as .lib and static.

Answer (score 0):

1. project properties -> linker -> input -> additional dependencies

- legacy_stdio_definitions.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

2. add source code

   C

   ```c
   FILE* __cdecl __iob_func(void)
   {
       FILE _iob[] = { *stdin, *stdout, *stderr };
       return _iob;
   }
   ```

   C++

   ```cpp
   extern "C" { FILE __iob_func[3] = { *stdin,*stdout,*stderr }; }
   ```